# Assign the data from JSON to an object directly in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is from https://angular.io/guide/http. It states that

> To access properties that are defined in an interface, you must explicitly convert the plain object you get from the JSON to the required response type.

```
.subscribe(data => this.config = {
  heroesUrl: (data as any).heroesUrl,
  textfile:  (data as any).textfile,
});
```

The config interface:

```
export interface Config {
  heroesUrl: string;
  textfile: string;
}
```

So the component code would be something like:

```
config: Config;

showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe(data => this.config = {
    heroesUrl: (data as any).heroesUrl,
    textfile:  (data as any).textfile,
});
}
```

I am trying to do something similar for my project; get the json and store it in an object. Is there a way to do it directly without the explicit assignment for every variable?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Not sure sure if I understand your question.

You can directly return on object instead of a type any of your backend returns the data structured properly.

```
return this.http.get<Config>().subscribe(config => ...);
```

This will return an observable of `Config`.

Answer (score 0):

i think its the only way, another form of the same way is passing the entire json data in a var, but then you will do the same on the html to take the specific value that you want from the json data response.
ex:

ts:

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig().subscribe(response => {
    this.data = response.data
    }
  });
}
```

html:

```
<span>
all the data : {{data}}
<br>
the heroesUrl : {{data.heroesUrl}}
<br>
the textfile : {{data.textfile}}
</span>
```